# Velocity appearing from nowhere when simulating orbiting bodies

Tags: c++, simulation, game-engine, physics, gravity

I am creating a game engine in c++ which has a very similar syntax as Unity.
I created a component called PointGravity which attracts all entities in the scene to it using newtons law of gravity.

However when testing this with a object orbiting it you would expect a wobble effect due to the PointGravity also pulling it to the object. But it wobbles much more in one direction than the other resulting it to move to the side, As seen here: [Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WExMN1jGknjy4k8qg9MLE5S459eqQIY-/view?usp=sharing)

m_entity is the entity which the pointgravity sits on
Here is the code:

```
void PointGravity::Update()
{
    mass = m_entity->GetComponent<RigidBody>()->mass; //Gets the mass from the rigidbody on the same entity

    std::vector<Entity*> entities = EntityManager::GetInstance()->GetEntities(); //Retrieves a vector list of all entities in the scene
    for (int i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++)
    {
        if (entities[i] == m_entity)
            continue;
        if (!entities[i]->GetComponent<RigidBody>())
            continue;
        if (entities[i]->GetComponent<RigidBody>()->ignoreGravity)
            continue;

        //Gravity calculation
        Vector3 direction = m_entity->GetComponent<Transform>()->position - entities[i]->GetComponent<Transform>()->position;
        float distance = direction.Magnitude();
        if (distance < 0.1)
            continue;

        //float massProduct = m_entity->GetComponent<RigidBody>()->mass * entities[i]->GetComponent<RigidBody>()->mass;

        float forceMagnitude = (m_entity->GetComponent<RigidBody>()->mass * entities[i]->GetComponent<RigidBody>()->mass) / pow(distance, 2) * 0.01;
        Vector3 force = direction.Normalize()*forceMagnitude;
        m_entity->GetComponent<RigidBody>()->AddForce(force*-1);
        entities[i]->GetComponent<RigidBody>()->AddForce(force);
    }

}
```

The yellow stone is the one which has the PointGravity on it and the brown stone has a tangential velocity to it of 10 an a position of 10 units above the yellow stone. I have no idea what is causing this issue.

Comment: One thing you'll want to do when writing fussy, math-heavy code like this is to write unit tests that verify on a very low-level that your calculations are correct. It's really hard to say by looking at this code if anything in here is perfectly valid.

Comment: Also if you're writing an engine I hope you have [*the book*](http://www.gameenginebook.com) on hand as a guide.

Comment: Your text is hard to understand, your question depends on a link to an external video, the video itself is very complex and the movement of the objects is not obviously wrong, your code is [neither complete nor minimal](https://stackoverflow.com), and you don't seem to have put any effort into checking things like Conservation of Momentum.

Comment: I tried to output the total momentum and it was so slightly increasing

Comment: Naïvely simulated harmonic oscillators are unstable. https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/12986/energy-of-damped-harmonic-oscillator-begins-increasing-with-very-large-q

Comment: @n.m. Thanks i now understand why the problem is how it is. I also tested it in unity yesterday and had the same problem